# Text from sqlite select is not formatted in the UI

Tags: cocoa, sqlite, text-formatting

I'm having an issue when displaying retrieved data from sqlite into UITextView.
My problem is that the \n character is only readed, and not applied

```
- (IBAction)cerca:(id)sender {
NSString *nome;
NSString *perche;
NSString *precauzioni;

const char *dbpath = [percorso UTF8String];
sqlite3_stmt    *statement;

if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &farmaciDB) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"SELECT * FROM farmaci WHERE nome=\"%@\"", stringa.text];        
    NSLog(@"Query: %@", querySQL);

    const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(farmaciDB, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    { 
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            nomeEtichetta.text=@"Nome";
            nome = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
            nomeText.text = nome;

            CGRect frameNome = nomeText.frame;
            frameNome.size.height = nomeText.contentSize.height;
            nomeText.frame = frameNome;

            percheEtichetta.text=@"Dettagio 1";
            perche = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
            //NSString* esc1 = [perche stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\r" withString:@"\\n"];

            percheText.text = perche;

            precauzioniEtichetta.text=@"Dettaglio 2";
            precauzioni = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];
            precauzioniText.text = precauzioni;

        } else {
                    NSLog(@"Error");
                } 
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    } else
    {
        NSLog(@"could not prepare statemnt: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(farmaciDB) );
    }
    sqlite3_close(farmaciDB);
}
}
```

and the result is :

Dato1: Descrizione1\nDato2: Descrizione2\nDato3: Descrizione3\n...

while I'd want:

```
Dato1: Descrizione1
Dato2: Descrizione2
Dato3: Descrizione3

....
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: This is not really a SQLite question but a UI question. So I added a tag. If not the right iOS library, please change it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the newline is escaped when you are inserting it into the SQLite database.
So your '\n' eventually becomes '\\n'.
If you have control over how the data is inserted, you could fix it there.

Otherwise you could replace the escaped newline with '\n':

```
[yourString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\n" withString:@"\n"];
```

Comment: I see the retrieved data as word1\nword2\n. Do you think it could be readed as \\n? I will try this. So far I solved by creating a html string and showing up in a uiwebview. But It is very strange this is the only way

Comment: You could have a look with a SQLite tool. Either via sqlite3 in Terminal or http://menial.co.uk/base/ , http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/ ,...